# How colums are read in database?

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design

Say I have 10 columns in Employee table where i just need to use two colums i.e. `salary and name` in below query

```
 select salary from Employee where name = 'Scott';
```

After going through [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRvkikVuojU) from 6.30 to 8.30(2 mins), My understanding is under RDBMS database(say oracle/Mysql etc) even i have to read two columns DBMS will read complete row from disc in memory then it will filter rows based on name coumn and finally read column salary. Is that correct  ?

Comment: That video...  It gives some good basics about how databases work, _but_ it ends up focusing on what I mentioned in my answer as a "Columnstore".  Please avoid learning about such until you have a good grasp of ordinary DB layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MySQL's InnoDB Engine...

Case 1 (slowest):  No index.  It will scan the entire table (all rows) to find one the row(s) with `name = 'Scott' and fetch`salary` from them.

Case 2:  `INDEX(name)`.  This will use the index to very efficiently the Scott row(s), then fetch the rows and get the salarys.

Case 3 (fastest):  `INDEX(name, salary)`.  Now the entire query can be performed inside just the index -- without reaching over to the rest of the columns in the data.  **More**  This is called a "covering" index.  More precisely:  If *all* the columns needed for the *entire* `SELECT` are found in the `INDEX`, then only the index need be touched, not the data.

The Data is in one BTree, ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  An `INDEX` is in a different BTree, ordered by the index.

BTrees are very efficient for finding a specific row or reading consecutive rows based on the index.  See the Wikipedia article on BTree.  This is also a good reference:  https://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/london-2011/PLUK2011-b-tree-indexes-and-innodb.pdf

For other databases, there could be differences.

**How a row is stored**

Case 1 *(most situations)*:  All the columns of a given table "record" (aka "row") are stored together in one contiguous set of dozens, maybe hundreds, of bytes.  And this is all sitting in the same "block" along with perhaps a hundred other rows.  So, when you grab any column from the row, all the rest of the columns are already readily available.  Your example of an `Employee` table probably falls into this Case.  RDBMS optimization focuses on being able to get an entire row quickly, but sacrifices in not being able to get an entire column quickly.

Case 2:  In some DB implementations (including MySQL's InnoDB) big columns (`TEXT` and `BLOB`) may be stored 'off record'.  That is, they are put in some other block(s).  Advantages (*) it allows for scanning rows quickly when you don't need those bulky pieces; (*) typically you will fetch the bulky columns for only one row at a time.

Case 3:  There is a different type of database organization, with names like "Columnstore".  This pivots the data so that it is easy to get all the values for a column quickly, but loses the ability to quickly get all the columns of a single row.

*Focus on Case 1, since it is very common.*

Comment: Question on case 2:- Will DBMS read the complete row(specific row after using index) with all columns from disc in memory and then use the columns present index. Right ? Question on case 3:- I think information contained in index is row location on disc. So even in this case complete row will be read from disc in memory and operation to map/return the column data will be done in memory . Is n't it?

Comment: @emilly: "Will DBMS read the complete row(specific row after using index) with all columns from disc in memory" basically yes (with some exception like blobs that might be stored elsewhere). "and then use the columns present index." unclear what you mean. The operation is complete after the first half of your sentence. "I think information contained in index is row location on disc. So even in this case complete row will ..." No. The index `INDEX(name, salary)` contains: `name`, `salary`, `primary key`. Since you do not need anything else in your query, no additional data has to be read.

Comment: @emilly, You and Solarflare are discussing a "covering" index.  I augmented my answer to bring out that term as it applies to my Case 3.

Comment: Thanks Rick and Solarflare. To be more clear on first question is `Will DBMS read the complete row(specific row after using index) with all columns from disc in memory and then works on the columns in memory as it needs to (based on query to then use the columns present index.)` Right ?

Comment: I added to my answer "how a row is stored".  And keep in mind my answer to your [_companion question_](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181536/applying-index-happens-in-memory-or-disc).

Comment: @RickJames when you say in case 1 `So, when you grab any column from the row, all the rest of the columns are already readily available..` I think you mean when you grab one column from row, That column and other columns of that row are fetched in cache and the dbms operate on column it need to ? For example in mine example `select salary from Employee where name = Scott` all that column data will be fetched in cache then DBMS will use only two columns i.e. `Salary` and `name` keeping in mind there is no index

Comment: For the simple Employee table, you get all the columns at once -- like grabbing your wallet - you get all the things in it.  As for "no index", actually cases 1 and 2 of indexing (not case 3 == "covering") apply.  You grab the whole record, giving you equal access to all columns.

Comment: "Grabbing a row" is one of the most costly activities in a DB.  (Granted we are talking about micro seconds.)  Grabbing a column out of that row, or doing some arithmetic on the columns -- these are cheaper operations.  DB optimization is _mostly_ about minimizing the the number of rows to fetch -- via indexing, or speeding up the fetch -- via caching.  The "covering index" optimization is less important.

Comment: @emilly - you still talk about 'reading' a row and/or a column.  Again, the smallest unit of IO for an oracle database is the BLOCK.  When making an I/O request, it is reading a complete block.  That complete block contains several _complete_ rows (blobs and row chaining aside for the moment).  Once it has a block, that block is placed the db block buffer.  From there _all_ identification of individual rows within the block and individual column values within the row, is an in-memory process. It is no more expensive to request 300 columns of a row than to request only 3 non-indexed columns.

Comment: And to continue from my previous comment ... Indexes are _also_ read _by the block_.  An index block is read and placed in the db buffer cache.  Then the block is parsed out (in memory) to determine which _data block_ needs to be requested. (Or it may detemine it needs to fetch another index block before it can get the information about the data block.

Comment: @EdStevens - emilly may have been confused by the Video she referenced -- it talks about regular databases, then talks about column-oriented dbs, which block things differently.

Comment: @RickJames - Good point.  After reviewing the video and the OP, I have two thoughts. 1) The video seemed to gloss over a lot, and 2) _every_ database product handles the nitty-gritty internals of getting data off a disk and presented to the client in a different manner.  I've only been addressing how Oracle does it.

Comment: MariaDB released Columnstore for its 10.1.19 late last year.  So, not just Oracle.  But certainly not "mainstream databases".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of relying on some dubious 3d party source, you should thoroughly review the official Oracle documentation, specifically, the [Concepts Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm), more specifically, the sections on [Physical Storage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT003) and [Logical Storage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT004).  That said, let me make a few specific points as they relate to your question(s).  First, Oracle does not really read rows from the disk.  It asks the OS to return 'x' bytes of data from file 'y', beginning at offset 'z'.  And the smallest number of bytes, the smallest unit of IO that it will request is the 'block'. And, it keeps a map, so it knows at what offset within a file each block is located.  All blocks within a given tablespace are teh same size, with the default being 8k. A block is a *logical* structure understood by Oracle but meaningless to the OS that is actually doing the I/O (or more precisely, transforming the request and passing it to the storage subsystem).  A block contains several rows, and the selection of individual rows, and specific columns, from the block is purely an in-memory (db buffer cache) operation.