# Applying Index happens in memory or disc?

Tags: mysql, oracle, index

Say I have 10k records in Customer table (MySQL or oracle) which has 10 columns. One is ID(primary key) and another is name(created index on it)

Now I search for word customer whose name is Alex. My understanding is first DBMS will determine the row location for record name `Alex` and then fetch those
rows in memory or it is other way round(where rows are fetched in memory then indexes are applied ?)

Comment: What would be the point of the index in your second case?

Comment: @emilly - You are on the verge of needing to understand the difference between how InnoDB uses the `ID` to locate the record versus how Oracle uses a "rownum".  Try not to go there until you have some more concepts well in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Study the concepts of "cache" and "block".*

In many situations, especially in databases, the data on disk is organized into "blocks".  When a block is needed (to satisfy some `SELECT` or `UPDATE` or whatever), it is requested.

Meanwhile, there is a "cache" in RAM that contains some of the blocks.

To satisfy the request for a block, the system first checks to see if the block is already in cache.  If it is not, *then* I/O is performed to bring a copy of the block from disk into RAM.  (For "persistence", the copy on disk must be considered the "source of truth", but let's not get into "ACID" in this discussion.)

Once the block is in the cache in RAM, the processing proceeds.

But, the cache is of a fixed size.  When there is not room in cache for a block, some block currently in cache must be pushed out of the way (and written back to disk if it is "dirty").

So...

Case 1:  Everything needed for the query is already in cache:  No I/O needed.

Case 2:  Some blocks are in cache:  Some I/O.

So...  Even if you have 10 *billion* records, and not nearly enough RAM to cache them, Case 2 says that the processing will (eventually, maybe in hours) finish with your query.

But... You mentioned indexing.  We just [*talked*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181530/how-colums-are-read-in-database) about how an index can get you to the desired row (think "block" in this view of the processing) by touching very few blocks.  With a suitable index (BTree or otherwise), the desired row can possibly be found by touching *very* few blocks.  And those blocks *might* already all be in cache.  Hence, *very* fast, perhaps less than a second, perhaps with no I/O, even with billions of rows.

Comment: I believe data comes to cache from block i.e. when we do any select it will check it will fetch the data from block(if not in cache) and then put it in cache for some time(Time is dependent on DB vendor and configuration) ?

Comment: Yes and No.  _First_ the block is read from disk into cache, _then_ the record is read from cache.  That is, the code _only_ understands how to manipulate rows in blocks in cache.  It cannot manipulate disk other than to read/write blocks.

Comment: This kind of cache does not have a TTL ("Time To Live").  A block stays in cache until it is bumped out by some other need.  It might stay in cache until you reboot the machine next year.  As long as the copy on disk and the copy in cache (RAM) are identical, everyone is happy.

Comment: You can't use your smartphone while it is sitting in your pocket/purse.  You must first bring it into your hand.  But your hand cannot also hold all of your keys, wallet, etc; they stay behind.  (Hand==cache; pocket/purse==disk)...

Comment: Wallet==block containing various records==credit cards, money, etc.  (No analogy for columns.)